# What is the difference between a subdivision surface modifier and a multiresolution modifier?

Tags: modifiers, workflow

I'm currently modeling my game character in Blender (see below picture). What is the difference between a subdivision surface modifier and a multiresolution modifier? I know they smooth the surface but are there specific characteristics to using each and what are those?

[image: low-poly character model]

Comment: This is a duplicate question only because the other question answered was migrated from gamedev.stackexchange.com. Is there any way to merge the answers given to each question so this is one post?

Answer (score 1):

There will be quite a difference in peoples workflow, but I would suggest something like this.
Start by making a high poly mesh. Then after you have modeled, sculpted and are done with the high poly mesh, move on the the low poly mesh. When you have established how your character will look, you can much better make a low poly mesh that will "fit" your character.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! What is the difference between a subdivision surface modifier and a multiresolution modifier? I know they smooth the surface but are there specific characteristics to using each and what are those? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Multiresolution](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Multiresolution) modifier gives the ability to subdivide a mesh to different levels depending on whether you are viewing it from the 3D Viewport, Sculpt Mode or a Blender Render.

The [Subdivision Surface](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf) modifier allows high resolution mesh modeling without the need to save and maintain huge amounts of data and gives a smooth organic look to the object.